# jQuery: Count elements and use the element number as CSS class

Tags: jquery, css, count, caption

I have an jquery script to generate a caption for images.
But now I want to count the elements with the caption an add the appropriate number as a class to the image class.
I know how I could count (.length) but how can i use the appropriate number from every element?

http://jsbin.com/ugemih/6/edit#javascript,html,live

BR

Comment: What do you mean by 'appropriate number' ?

Comment: Sorry for my englisch. I mean the exact number from the counted element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass a variable to the function passed to `each()` and it will hold the current element's number:

```
$('.foo').each(function (i) {
    $(this).addClass('foo-' + i);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically modifying the class name can be achieved this way.

```
$('.test').each(function (e) { 
    $(this).addClass('test_' + e); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is set the class of an element, that's super easy with *or* without jQuery!  Quick use of the jQuery [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function will allow you to change any class, namely, class.

```
$("[div to change]").attr("class", "[class_name]" + [number]);
```

Here I've set the `class` to `[class_name][1,2,3...]`.  So if `[class_name]` were `hello` and `[number]` were `5`, it would set the `class` to `hello5`.

Alternatively if you want to ADD a `class` to the object (keeping any in place styling in tact) you can use jQuery's [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) function:

```
$("[div to change]").addClass("[class_name]" + [number]);
```

This will add a similarly named `class` to your object.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't use css?
There is a pseudo-selector, nth-child.

```
a:nth-child(1){color: #123;}
a:nth-child(2){color: #456;}
a:nth-child(3){color: #789;}
```

And so on.

Using [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) will make this work in IE6 to 8. After that, nth-child is supported.
It means you can start writing smarter, standards based css now, and the script will make it work in IE.

You can do everything in javascript if you want, but you should use css for applying styles, and if you can do that instead of adding classes using javascript, your site will be more efficient, and easier to maintain.

Comment: I havn´t use css3 for this site yet. And the IE has some problems with this in older versions.
And if I use jQuery to generate the captions why not use it also for this which will work in older IE.

Comment: Selectivzr may be of great addition, I've added it to my answer.